# How to use angular2-local-storage module in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

How do I use this module in Angular 2? Any examples?

So far I installed the module and imported in the Angular 2 component.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-local-storage

Answer (score 8):

Import it and add it to `bootstrap()`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProvider, LocalStorage]);
```

Inject it into the component, directive, or service where you want to use it.

```
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private ls:LocalStorage) {}
  clickHandler() {
    this.ls.set('someKey', 'someValue');
  }
  otherClickHandler() {
    console.log(this.ls.get('someKey'); // should print 'someValue'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I did it, but still have problem and this error: 
`local_storage:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
 Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2-local-storage/local_storage
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to `LocalStorage`. I can't help you with this because I use Dart and have no knowledge about TS imports and similar. There are lots of questions about similar error messages already "Unexpected token <". If you don't find anything that fits, I guess it's best to create a new question for this specific error.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same issue and after debugging code I found the solution.

Issue is with npm package creation not in the source code.

When you run "npm install angular2-localStorage", it download package in node_module folder but in web deployment, that folder goes outside of node_module.
Because of this, website can not find the package hence the error you get in browser.

I have copied those 2 files "LocalStorage.ts" and "LocalStorageEmitter.ts" and referred directly in my code.

It works like a charm!

Comment: Just because it is missing from your command example, don't know if it's just a typo or what, actual command should be `npm install --save angular2-localStorage`

Comment: command is                                                                                              "npm install --save angular2-localstorage    "                                        please refer this link   https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localStorage

Answer (score 2):

What are you using for your developement enviroment?

If you are using SystemJS like the angular2 tutorials, you'll need to add the following to your systemjs.conf.js file:

in the map area you'll need to add:

'angular2-localstorage': 'node_modules/angular2-localstorage'

For example:

```
var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-localstorage':      'node_modules/angular2-localstorage'
  };
```

Depending on your setup, you may also need to add:

```
'angular2-localstorage': {
    defaultExtension: "js"
}
```

to your "packages" area.

Then, in your main bootloader you'll want to import it:

```
import {LocalStorageService, LocalStorageSubscriber} from 'angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter';
```

And update the bootloader and subscribe:

for example:

```
var appPromise = bootstrap(myapp, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocalStorageService]);
LocalStorageSubscriber(appPromise);
```

Then... to actually use it, you'll do something like this within a class:

Import it:

```
import {LocalStorage, SessionStorage} from "angular2-localstorage/WebStorage";
```

Then, within the class:

```
@LocalStorage() public foo:string = ''; // this will initialize to empty string, you might want something different.
this.foo = this.foo + "Changed";  //foo variable and '/foo' localstorage entry will change any time the variable changes. *note, but not the other way around
```

Comment: I'm using angular2-seed and I've tried following your instructions but I get a 404 error on the LocalStorageEmitter.js and WebStorage.js files:

GET http://localhost:5555/node_modules/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.js 404 (Not Found)

The angular2-localstorage module only includes those files as TypeScript (.ts) files, so I guess they need to be transpiled at some point - just not sure when or how. Any ideas?

Comment: Typically a 404 would suggest a problem with the systemjs config.

I'm not using angular2-seed, so I'm unsure.  My guess would be that your typings setup isn't transpiling the files correctly... I don't know enough about typings to help.

Comment: Thanks lowcrawler, I managed to fix it by setting the transpiler option to 'typescript' on the SystemJS config

Comment: Been looking at this same problem for hours. I also get this 404 not found error `http://localhost:4200/node_modules/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter`   Tried setting the transpiler option to typescript, does not work for me. Tried code above, does not work either for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent upon your dev. environment, specifically the tools being used to compile your typescript.  If you are using SystemJS, you need to map to it in your config file. For info on how this works, here [is a link to the config](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#systemjs) of the [Angular 2's official "Tour of Heroes" quick-start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) which uses SystemJS.

```
map: {
    'angular2-localstorage': 'node_modules/angular2-localstorage'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug with this library. I am using the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to generate an Angular 2 application. As a sanity check, I tried the [angular2-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie) package. Note that the instructions on how to install and use this package with Angular 2 is outdated.

Step 1. Install the package.

`npm install angular2-cookie --save`

Step 2. modify SystemJS settings in `system-config.ts`

```
const map: any = {
 'angular2-cookie': 'vendor/angular2-cookie'
}

const packages: any = {
 'angular2-cookie' : {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  }
}
```

Step 3. modify the angular-cli build script `angular-cli-build.js`

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
      'angular2-cookie/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

Step 4. Provide the service in `main.ts`

```
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
...
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  CookieService
])
.catch( (err:any) => console.error(err));
```

Step 5. You can load your application with `ng serve`, but after the 4 steps above, you will have to kill it (e.g. ctrl-c) and restart it `ng serve`.

Now, if you repeat these 5 steps with `angular2-localstorage`, it will NOT work.

Step 1. install

`npm install --save angular2-localstorage`

Step 2. `system-config.ts`

```
const map: any = {
  'angular2-cookie': 'vendor/angular2-cookie',
  'angular2-localstorage': 'vendor/angular2-localstorage'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'angular2-localstorage': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'ts'
  },
  'angular2-cookie' : {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  }
}
```

Step 3. `angular-cli-build.js`

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
      'angular2-cookie/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'angular2-localstorage/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

Step 4. `main.ts`

```
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter';
...
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  CookieService,
  LocalStorageService
])
.catch( (err:any) => console.error(err));
```

Step 5. kill and restart `ng-serve`

You will observe something like the following.

```
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:4200/main.js:8:29)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/main.js:27:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:4200/main.js:28:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.ts
    Evaluating http://localhost:4200/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:4200/main.js ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: (SystemJS) SyntaxError: Unexpected token import(…)
```

If you try to change `system-config.ts` as one of the users advised like the following.

```
'angular2-localstorage': {
    defaultExtension: "js"
}
```

Then, you will see the following.

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.js 404 (Not Found)
```

It doesn't matter if you add or remove `format: 'cjs'`, you will still get a 404.

Of course, one difference is that `angular2-cookie` is written in `JavaScript` and `angular2-localstorage` is written in `TypeScript`. But still, the ideas should be the same.

It seems to me the console complains about the `import` statement.

[This ticket](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage/issues/50) suggest you need to build the package (because there is a bug with npm), but the user still said even that doesn't work.

I don't think there's anything we can do at this point about this package (as users).

Oh, on the project's website.

> This project is not maintained. Please consider taking it over. More information at https://github.com/open-source-chest/take-it-over.